# google map info window with ajax v3

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I've almost got it, but it doesn't quite work.  I'm trying to load the content via ajax, and it does load the correct content, I can see it loading in firebug however, it gives me an error: infowindow not defined.  I've got something out of place with `load_content`

The two commented out lines before load_content work to load a little window with some text.

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @location_for_map.average(:lat) %>, <%= @location_for_map.average(:lng) %>);
  var myOptions = {
   zoom: 13,
   center: myLatlng,
   mapTypeControl: false,
   navigationControl: true,
   navigationControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
   },
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  //var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  setMarkers(map, places);

 }

 function setMarkers(map, locations) {
   // Add markers to the map

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var place = locations[i];
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place.lat, place.lng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: '/images/google_maps/numbers/'+(i+1)+'.png',
    html: place.name,
    id: place.id,
          title: place.name
      });

   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     //infowindow.setContent(this.html);
     //infowindow.open(map,this);
     load_content(marker, this.id);

   });
  }
 }

 function load_content(marker, id){
   $.ajax({
     url: '/places/' + id + '.js',
     success: function(data){

       infowindow.setContent(data);
       infowindow.open(map, marker);
     }
   });
 } 

 function loadScript() {
     var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.type = "text/javascript";
     script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
     document.body.appendChild(script);
 }
```

Comment: what does it load if not the content? do a console.log(data) inner your success callback to see in firebug.

Comment: it does load the content remotely (the correct content), it just doesn't display it by popping up the infowindow.  It loads in the background (i can see with firebug) and then breaks with "infowindow not defined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  // Add markers to the map

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var place = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place.lat, place.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: '/images/google_maps/numbers/'+(i+1)+'.png',
            html: place.name,
            id: place.id,
            title: place.name
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          load_content(map,this,infowindow);      
        });
    }
}

function load_content(map,marker,infowindow){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/places/' + marker.id + '.js',
    success: function(data){
      infowindow.setContent(data);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your infowindow declaration has scope only inside the function.  Try declaring the infowindow variable with global scope.  I believe that's what's causing the 'infowindow not defined' problem.

Comment: i tried adding it above to the initializer function, but it had no effect.

Comment: did you try global? that is above the initializer function?

Answer (score 0):

Move this line:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

to be outside any function, eg just after function initialize(){}

Comment: well, if i move it outside of any function i get "google is not defined" ;-)